# How do I properly set up my useEffect so I don't receive a missing dependency warning?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, dependencies

I am receiving this warning "React Hook React.useEffect has missing dependencies: 'fetchData' and 'source'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps".  This is my function:

```
function EmployeesPage(props: any) {

    const companyId = props.match.params.id;

    const source = axios.CancelToken.source();

    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get<IEmployees[]>(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/api/company/${companyId}/employees`, {
                cancelToken: source.token
            });
            setEmployees(response.data);
            setLoading(true);
        } catch (error) {
            if (axios.isCancel(error)) {

            } else {
                throw error;
            }

        }
    }

    const deleteEmployee = async (EmployeeId: any) => {

        const response = await axios.delete(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/api/company/${companyId}/employees/${employeeId}`);
        if (response) await fetchData();   
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
        return () => {
            source.cancel();
        };

    }, [])
```

I tried to fix this by putting fetchData inside of the useEffect and moving the deleteEmployee out, but this causes my endpoint to be called in an infinite loop.  Then I tried the useCallback function and also created an infinite loop.

```
const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get<IEmployees[]>(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/api/company/${companyId}/employees`, {
                cancelToken: source.token
            });
            setEmployees(response.data);
            setLoading(true);
        } catch (error) {
            if (axios.isCancel(error)) {

            } else {
                throw error;
            }

        }
    }, [source, CompanyId]);
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
        return () => {
            source.cancel();
        };

    }, [fetchData, source])

    const deleteEmployee = async (EmployeeId: any) => {

       
        await axios.delete(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/api/company/${companyId}/employees/${employeeId}`);
       
    }
```

It is my understanding that the only thing that should be going in the dependency array would be something that is going to change.  I think my dependency array should be empty because I don't want anything to change.  It is going to be the same data being returned each time unless a new employee is added.  I'm not sure how to fix this to get the warning message to go away.  I have see that there is a way to disable the warning but I am not sure I should do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect runs in an infinite loop since the `source` object changes in every render. Move it inside the effect. And move the `fetchData` function inside the effect as well since it needs access to `source`.

You should add `companyId` to the dependencies array to make sure the data is refetched when `companyId` changes. The `setEmployees` and `setLoading` references don't change so it is safe to add them - they won't cause the effects to re-run.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  const source = axios.CancelToken.source()

  const fetchData = async () => {
    //...
  }

  fetchData()

  return () => {
    source.cancel()
  }
}, [companyId, setEmployees, setLoading])
```

I would recommend reading [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies) to understand if it is safe to omit functions from the dependencies array.

Comment: thank you for your help.  This worked except for calling fetchData with source as a parameter.  I just did it like this fetchData() and it worked.  I have a global variable companyId that is being taken inside my url for get and delete requests.  It is also used outside fetchData.  I am getting a missing dependency warning on this as well.  Do you how to fix that?  I don't think it should go in the dependency array because it won't be changing.

Comment: @dev_in_training You have to add `companyId` to the dependencies array since you have to re-fetch data if the company id changes. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could declare both `fetchData` and `source` inside the `useEffect`, since it does not use anything besides `setState` functions. This way, `fetchData` won't be  declared over and over on each re-render.

```
useEffect(() => {
   const source = axios.CancelToken.source();
   const fetchData = async () => {
      ...
   };

   fetchData();

   return () => {
      source.cancel();
   };
}, [setEmployee, setLoading]);
```

Comment: The `fetchData` function needs access to the `source` object. So, it has to be inside the effect as well.

Comment: As suggested, you could move `fetchData` inside the `useEffect` as well. And pass the setState functions as dependencies. These functions always have the same reference.

Comment: @ArunKumarMohan true. Thanks for the observation

Comment: @Nihil and ArunKumarMohan Thank you for your help.  This works but I still get a missing dependency for the companyId.  It is a global variable so if I put it inside the useEffect, the other functions won't be able to use it.  I am not sure how to handle that.